# How create Box what overlap few items in LazyColumn

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Lazy Column, which is a timeline. Each element is an hour of time. I need to draw task cards on top of the timeline. The task can take more than one hour, respectively, it can take one time cell, two and one and a half.
Question - is it possible to draw something like a Box on top of several elements with reference to their position?
Example what I need https://i.imgur.com/M1bBG4T.png